# PHP Поиск MySQL

Tags: mysql, php, sql

**У меня есть запрос к бд:**

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '%$search%'") or die(" <b>Ошибка поиска строки</b> ");
```

и сама бд: 
[image]

После попыток поиск стал находить только по запросу "Имя" или "Фамилия" (((

Поиск должен находить такие запросы:

> Имя Фамилия
> Фамилия Имя
> Фамилия
> Имя

В базе данных, в столбце name информация хранится так: *Имя Фамилия*

 На запрос "Имя" он находит много людей и успешно их выводит.

Любой из вариантов выше может быть передан в переменную $search.

:

Comment: А имя фамилия - это одна колонка или две? 

Comment: одна

Comment: добавь к вопросу содержание таблицы и запросы к базе - посмотрим.

Answer (score 1):

```
$parts = explode(" ", $search);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '".mysql_real_escape_string("%".$parts[0]."%").isset($parts[1])?" AND name like '".mysql_real_escape_string("%".$parts[1]."%")."'":'') or die(" <b>Ошибка поиска строки</b> ");
```

как то так

**UPD**
Да, согласен, поправил. Но вы могли бы и сами обнаружить очепятку :)

Comment: Ошибка поиска строки при любом запросе

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in T:\home\localhost\www\searchName.php on line 71
Ошибка поиска строки

в строке $result ошибка

Answer (score 0):

в коде предложенном [@shurik](/users/1182/shurik)

```
$parts = explode(" ", $search);
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE name like '".mysql_real_escape_string("%".$parts[0]."%").isset($parts[1])?" AND name like '".mysql_real_escape_string("%".$parts[1]."%")."'":'') or die(" <b>Ошибка поиска строки</b> ");
```

в SQL рассматривается возможность, когда в запросе присутствует имя и фамилия, а что если будет только одна часть? Тогда у нас нет пробела, по которому можно было бы бить строку, соответственно паттерн соберается у нас вот такой "%%", что ведет к ошибке MySQL, которую и наблюдает автор вопроса.
Соотвественно, если добавим костылик проверки на пробел вначале, думаю заработает. Итого заменим часть

```
$parts = explode(" ", $search);
```

на вариант с проверкой:

```
$parts = array();
if (strpos($search, ' ')) {
    $parts = explode(" ", $search);    
} else {
    $parts[] = $search;
}
```